# how to send the domain instance back to the client in case of Grails validation errors

Tags: rest

I just started to learn Grails and my question of this could be dumb. So apologies if it is dumb. I have a client program and a REST web service - both coded by me. The client program calls the RESTful service using POST (to add record to a database). When I call object.save() there are some validation errors that are returned.

In my gsp I have fieldError tag coded to read the error message for each field in the bean and show it in the screen. I'm assuming I needed to pass the domain instance that failed the validation from RESTful service to the client so the client could inturn send it to gsp which will automatically show errors. Correct me if this is wrong. however I don't know how to pass the domain instance object as XML from the web service. When the validations are successful though, I get the object like "render object as XML". However when validations fail, I don't know how to pass the entire failed domain instance object back as xml.

I tried to code,

```
                if (student.save()){
          render student as XML
        } else {

            student.errors.each(){
            println it 
            }
        def errmsg = student.errors.allErrors.collect {      g.message(error:it) }

           render(contentType:"text/xml") {
                respstud {
                    for(err in errmsg) {
                        message(err)
                        }
                    }
            }


        }
```

This returned the specific error message back to the client as xml, but I'm needing the entire student object to be sent back to the client when save() fails also. Can someone please help?

let me know if you need more info. This is my first post in stackoverflow so I don't really know if I have to provide more details. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Prem

Comment: Here is my gsp code that renders errors for each field.               ${label}: <span class="errors">
 <g:fieldError bean="${bean}" field="${field}" />
</span>
<br/>
<g:textField name="${name + '.' +field}"
             value="${fieldValue(bean:bean, field:field)}" />

Answer (score 0):

Because the request is being made via ajax, you will need to handle it the Ajax way.

Your gsp is compiled on the server and sent as html to the client when the page is first requested.

One way to handle this would be to set an error on the ajax response and return a snippet of the code you would like to render.

The response may then be handled in the error section of your calling JavaScript and the code snippet rendered on the page where you wish.

Comment: Thanks. Im not using AJAX. not sure if I was clear i just wanted to pass back the domain object instance (per my above example it will be student object) which I wanted to pass along back to the calling client. The reason i wanted to pass the object back was it already has errors (Spring interface) set and if I can just somehow send this student object back to the client I can then parse the object and read fieldErrors in my gsp. Please help!